# Facebook Insights api: Auto export to google sheets setup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-sheets

To start off...i do not really know what I am doing and I have been searching for solutions and piecing things together but now I am totally confused!

I have been given admin rights to a client's Facebook page with the intention of wanting to automatically export all of the Insights data every hour into a Google Sheet.

I have registered with Facebook Graph and I have setup a new app (iOS) with an App ID and APP Secret. I also have a Page Access Token for the client's Facebook page (expires jan 2017).

I have been looking around trying to work out how I get the data from Insights into a Google sheet using a combination of Formulas and Google Scripts. I found a blog which gave me instructions on setting up a Google Sheet and the following script:

```
function facebookLikes(url){
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  var likes = data.likes;
  return likes;
}

function storeLikes(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = datarange.getNumRows();
    var numColumns = datarange.getNumColumns();
    var nextColumn = numColumns + 1;
    sheet.getRange(1, nextColumn).setValue(new Date());
    for (var i=2; i <= numRows; i++){
      var numLikes = sheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
      sheet.getRange(i, numColumns + 1).setValue(numLikes);
    }
}
```

Then using some formulas to supposedly pull through the page's number of Likes:

=CONCAT(httpsxxx.graph.facebook.com/",A1)

=facebooklikes(b1)

I get the following error message:

"Request failed for graph.facebook.com/{page name} returned code 400..."

It goes on to say I need an access token to request this resource. Again, after searching around I found this GitHub source: https://github.com/oshliaer/apps-script-oauth2/blob/facebook/samples/Facebook.gs Is there a way to combine these scripts or am I barking up the wrong tree?

I am now totally out of my depth, I don't know if what I have found/done is anywhere remotely near what I want to acheive.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be grateful - I am totally new to scripts and API's so any help would have to be easy to follow steps.

Ultimatley I want to create a spreadsheet that holds and updates all the data shown under each Insight heading.

Is this even possible??

Thank you